# Prove any two vectors have a non orthogonal vector

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I am trying to prove that any two (non zero) given vectors  of $\mathbb{R}^n$ have at least one vector which is *not* orthogonal to any of them. 
Thank you very much, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v$ and $w$ be the vectors. If they are orthogonal, take $v+w$. Otherwise, take $v$.

Comment: @חנניהמאיר If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Just did . Thanks